# How do you get the url of the script your running in Google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

If your making a script using the Google script editor, how do you get the url of the script your running in the google script editor in google docs? (sorry for not capitalizing the word google)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question, you can choose the "Publish" -> "Deploy As a Web App..." menu item.  From there, the pop-up will show "Deploy as Web App" with a text box underneath containing the URL.  Grab that (or click the "latest code" link just below it).  You don't have to follow-through on the re-deploy (if you do, you'll want to use the URL it presents in a pop-up after doing so)

If you haven't previously deployed it, you'll need to save a "version" and deploy it, as touched on [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps).  Upon doing that, it will present you with the Url in a pop-up as mentioned above.  If you miss it, the the first part of this answer applies.